# Generation of source code based on specification files

Tags: scala, code-generation, scala-3

I am starting a new project in Scala (my first one in this language) and I'm trying to automate modelling my main data class. I want to have a specification file from which I can just generate the data class as well as import/export functionality to at least one file format.

I want to write a small program that will convert the specification file into source code and store the generated code on disk (in .scala files). I know that I could use a macro to generate the classes, but then they would only be generated at the compilation step and I wouldn't have a way to look at the generated code files in any editor (nor would the IDE know that these data classes exist and what structure they have, so I assume that my IDE would throw many errors at me).

So my question is:

- How can I generate the source files in a most elegant way?
- Can I use the TASTy classes that provide an API for code generation during the compiling step, but not use them inside a macro but instead use them in the main (helper) program and store the results in text files?

UPDATE:
A small update, because the question seems not to be clear:

Assume I have a simple case class:

```
case class MyStruct(
    val myValue: Int
    val myId: String
)
```

I want to write instances of this class to a custom file format, so I need an exporter class, which I have to write (or generate) on my own. Writing this exporter is easy, but since the struct is not closed (it might be extended with more fields during development of the program), I would have to also edit the exporter class each time I add another field. This is a problem, because the modelling of the struct will be done by business analysts, not by software architects, so they might not have the knowledge how to extend the exporter class. So my idea is to take the struct, use retrospection and generate the exporter class based on the definition of the struct.

I know that I can use macros for compile time retrospection and that i can use the AST provided to the macros to generate classes which are compiled into the program, but can I also export the classes to source files?

A little more compicated: The structs are not defined in source files, but in a table format (like a plain csv file), because this file will also contain meta information (like description of the fields). Can I read the specification file during compile time and use this instead of retrospection, but still use the scala AST definitions to generate the source files?

Comment: It's hard to answer anything since you haven't told us anything about the specification format, requirements, etc. In general it would require writing some parser, defining some AST, probably some config, and then a generator which would turn several AST values with config value into several `String`s. For that any parser-combinator library would be OK (except scala-parser-combinators, I'd advise against it). More specifically you could use existing language (like Scala) to define both specification and configuration, and output Strings from some scala-cli script.

Comment: If you want to read Scala files there is something called Tasty Inspector - but I would NOT recommend reading generic Scala code and then using it in code generation - there are too many corner cases and different allowed trees that this codegen would be over-complicated by design. Smaller, dedicated language (or just DSL in existing programming language) would be much simpler and faster to deliver.

Comment: You can have a source generator task in **sbt** and you can look at the generated code - Also, take a look at some IDL languages like **smithy** or **dhal**.

Comment: Macros in general do not write to separate files. Macro methods are generating code and inlining it where the method was called, and macro annotations receive AST of what they annotated and return a modified AST of it. They can create new classes, but these classes are anonymous for you, and you will NOT be able to read them in IDE. IME allowing external non-technical people to specify everything is a DOA attempt - domain object are used only by programmers, so they should define them, DTOs can be generated from OpenAPI/AsyncAPI/Protobufs, experts can provide CSV and other data uses in tests.

Comment: Just write your "specification" files in scala 